# How to determine environment when running DotNetCore console app in docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, console-application

I'm trying to determine the environment so I know which appsettings.json file to read from.

I've got the code below which, from Googling, seems to be the accepted way of achieving this (I'm more than happy to consider other ways to do this if there are better ways???):

```
var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
Console.WriteLine($"Environment: {environmentName}");

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", false, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

_configuration = builder.Build();
```

The above works fine when running locally, getting the value from the system variables:

[image: System variables]

If I run the app in a docker container however, `environmentName` is empty.

How do I set the environment variables in docker?

I have tried a few ways of achieving this but none of them have the desired effect:

In my dockerfile I had:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/myapp.dll","--environment=test"]
```

I also tried to pass it as a parameter when running the container:

```
docker run -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=test --rm dotnetapp-dev
```

In my last example above, I did notice that I could get the parameter by calling this code AFTER I've built the config but it's too late there - I need it before calling `Build()`:

```
_configuration = builder.Build();
Console.WriteLine(_configuration["ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"]);//this works
```

Has anyone managed to achieve setting system variables in a docker container?

Comment: In your docker file add `ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Production"`.
You can also define a default value in your cs file. Like aspnetcore does.

Comment: This was another of my attempts but that doesn’t seem to work either.

Comment: Did you try to remove the `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine` parameters ?

Comment: At least you can create your configuration object in two phase. But it's ugly

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by EnvironmentVariable.Machine parameters...?

Comment: Yes I could do it in two stages but it’s dirty... I will probably just copy the docker config file to the standard config file as part of the deployment if I can’t get the environment variables working

Comment: Replace `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)` by `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")`

Comment: Oh I see what you mean... I needed that when running the code locally but I don’t think I tried it without in a docker container. I will try that and let you know.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/94e9d02ad70b2224d012ac4a66eaa1f913ae4f29/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Environment.NoRegistry.cs) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Environment.cs#L32), the EnvironmentVariableTarget only support User and Machine on windows. This is why all your previous tests didn't work

Comment: OK so if I remove `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine` it works in Docker - great - but doesn't work locally....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Kalten I managed to get a solution that works - it seems really easy looking at the code but was a bit of a pain to get to:

```
const string environmentVariableName = "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT";
var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(environmentVariableName, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(environmentName))
{
    //this is required for docker
    environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(environmentVariableName);
}

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", false, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

_configuration = builder.Build();
```

This line is the only way I could get the system variables when running locally, but this doesn't work for docker:

```
var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(environmentVariableName, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

This line is the only way I could get the system variables when running in docker, but this doesn't work locally:

```
var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(environmentVariableName);
```

I have had to get `environmentName` using both methods with a check for null after the first. Not Ideal but it works and I won't have to rename appsettings.json files which was one of my options when I couldn't seem to get anything from docker.

So in docker I can pass in the variable as an argument: `docker run -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging --rm dotnetapp-dev` or I can put the variable in the dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
WORKDIR /app

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Regression
//other stuff here
```